# How can I find the difference between two images of different scales and sizes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, pixel

I have two images `image1` and `image2` that are represented as 2D numpy arrays. I'd like to find the difference image between the two, which I think would simply be `diff = image1-image2`. However, the problem is that the two images are different sizes, and have different pixel scales.

`image1` has shape (600, 600) and pixel scale = 2.757/5 arcseconds. `image2` has shape (641, 641) and pixel scale = 0.275 arcseconds. They both have also been normalized so that the total sum of the pixels in the 2D array is 1.

It doesn't make sense to get a pixel-by-pixel difference (difference image) unless they both have the same pixel scale, and in order to take the difference they have to be the same shape. I'm confused on how to do this, since if I oversample or undersample one of them to achieve the same pixel scale, the shapes will still be different. Is this possible?

Comment: [ndimage.zoom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html) can bring the images to the same shape. If the pixel scale is important, you don't have to do any computations: just say that the images are different because one of them shows a larger region than the other.

Comment: I think you should consider the real distance spanned by each image. Then to compare you zoom the smaller (in real distance units) image to the pixel scale of the larger image, you align the images (you have to find the correspondence between them for comparison.. is it the principal point?), and then you crop the larger image to the borders of the smaller image. Then, you can compare

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure that both images have the same pixel scale by multiplying the `image2` by the pixel scale of `image1` and `image1` by the pixel scale of `image2`. Then I would either `zoom` (see [`scipy`'s `zoom` example here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.zoom)) `image1` or shrink `image2` so that both images have the same size before taking the difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplying the image2 by the pixel scale"?  `pixel_scale1 * image2` does not make any geometric sense.

Comment: The multiplication I am talking about here is **scalar multiplication** which can me interpreted geometrically as either **stretching (zooming in)** or **shrinking (zooming out)** the image. Please take a look at the Wikipedia page for scalar matrix multiplication [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication). I think you need to keep in mind what we want to achieve.

Comment: Ah, I see. You don't know what you are talking about.  As I thought.